# Show that if $ p\mid n$ then $\phi(np)=p\phi(n)$

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, totient-function

The question:

> Let $n\in\Bbb N$ and let $p$ be a prime. Show that if  $ p\mid n$ then
>    $\phi(np)=p\phi(n)$.

What I know is:

- It is related to Euler's totient function $\phi$
- $\phi$($n$)= # of $+$ve integers that are less than n and are relatively prime
- prime numbers$>=1$
- $\phi$($p$)=$p-1$, where $p$ is a prime number
- $ p\mid n$ means that $p$ divides $n$ such that $n=kp$, where $k\in\Bbb N$.
- $\phi$($n$)= $\phi$($n$) because $p\mid$n and only $n$, so it can't divide the numbers that are not divided by $n$ itself, which are $ϕ$(n).

I don't know how to prove it as I don't understand how come $\phi$$(np)$=$p$$\phi$($n$)?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I suppose you mean Euler's totient function $\phi$? It has nothing to do with the empty set $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but we learned in that name.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I read it and used it.

Comment: Hint: Start by figuring out what $\phi(p^n)$ is if $p$ is prime.. Another property of $\phi$ that will help is that $\phi$ is multiplicative: if $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$.

Comment: I suggest you read it again. @TasneemZh

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I thought it was that symbol. I have changed it now that I have noticed the mistake.

Comment: @rogerl Thanks for the clarifications. I will start thinking of it.

Comment: @rogerl - ϕ(p$^{n}$) = a nonprime number, so its answer will be less than (p-1). gcd(n,p)$\neq$1, since p|n, which means that there is already a common number k between them. Thus, ϕ(pn)$\neq$ϕ(p)ϕ(n), so?

Comment: Count the numbers $\le p^k$ that are not prime to $p^k$. That should let you find a nice formula for $\phi(p^k)$. Once you do that, and use the fact that $\phi$ is multiplicative by writing $pn = p^km$ where $p\nmid m$, things should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @rogerl I have tried to solve it with your hints but didn't get to any result as they seemed ambiguous back then. Now, they look pretty clear and understandable after I got the answer... Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

It comes with a hint which is to consider the prime factorization of $n$. *(The one who gave me the question didn't declare the hint)*.

**Since $p | n$, the prime factorization of n is**

$n = $$p^e$$p^{e_1}_1$$p^{e_2}_2$$\cdots$$p^{e_k}_k$, **for some $k$.**

**Thus**

$ϕ(n) = ϕ($$p^e)$ $ϕ($$p^{e_1}_1$$p^{e_2}_2$$\cdots$$p^{e_k}_k)$

**We know that $ϕ(n) = p-1$, and since it is $p.p.p\cdots$ $e$ times, so we took one $p$ and multiplied the rest $p^{e-1}$ with it**

$ϕ(n)= (p − 1)$$p^{e−1}$ $ϕ($$p^{e_1}_1$$p^{e_2}_2$$\cdots$$p^{e_k}_k)$

$ϕ(np) = ϕ($$p^{e+1}$$p^{e_1}_1$$p^{e_2}_2$$\cdots$$p^{e_k}_k)$

**As they are primes, their $gcd$ for every two of them is $1$, thus we can use this rule:**

> $ϕ(mn)=ϕ(m)ϕ(n)$

$= ϕ($$p^{e+1}) ϕ($$p^{e_1}_1$$p^{e_2}_2$$\cdots$$p^{e_k}_k)$

$= (p − 1)$$p^e$ $ϕ($$p^{e_1}_1$$p^{e_2}_2$$\cdots$$p^{e_k}_k)$

$= pϕ(n)$